# Conjugacy in $\text{GL}(2, \mathbb{Z})$ vs $\text{GL}(2, \mathbb{Q})$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, general-linear-group

When are two elements $x,y\in\text{GL}(2, \mathbb{Z})$ conjugate in $\text{GL}(2, \mathbb{Q})$, but not in $\text{GL}(2, \mathbb{Z})$? Does this ever happen? I feel that it should sometimes be the case, but cannot come up with any concrete examples.

EDIT: so it is possible; but is it possible if we require the conjugating element in $\text{GL}(2, \mathbb{Q})$ to have determinant $\pm 1$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $n \times n$ matrices, not just $2 \times 2$ matrices, if  the characteristic polynomial of the two matrices is *irreducible* over $\mathbf Q$ then the distinction between their conjugacy as rational matrices and as integral matrices is directly related to ideal classes in algebraic number theory. See [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/matrixconj.pdf). For instance, the example given by Dietrich Burde is two matrices sharing irreducible characteristic polynomial $x^2-6x-1$, whose roots are $3\pm\sqrt{10}$, and the ring generated by either root is $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{10}]$, which has two ideal classes: see Example 3.2 at the link.

Answer (score 8):

Take $A = (\begin{smallmatrix}0&1\\1&6\end{smallmatrix})$ and $B = (\begin{smallmatrix}3&5\\2&3\end{smallmatrix})$. These matrices are both in ${\rm GL}_2({\Bbb Z})$, but they are not conjugate in this group. Indeed, any matrix $M = (\begin{smallmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{smallmatrix})$ satisfies $MA = BM$ if and only if $b=3a+5c$ and $d = 2a+3c$, and then $\det M = 2a^2 - 5c^2$. We can't solve $2a^2 - 5c^2 = \pm 1$ in ${\Bbb Z}$ - look at it modulo $5$. Note that any matrix $M$ in $GL_2(\Bbb Z)$ has determinant $\pm 1$. However, over $\Bbb Q$ the determinant can be every nonzero rational number. So it is easy to see, that they are conjugated in $GL_2(\Bbb Q)$. For example, take $M=(\begin{smallmatrix}1&8\\1&5\end{smallmatrix})$.

Comment: Huh, interesting. Is this still true if we require the conjugating element in $\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{Q})$ to have determinant $\pm 1$?

Comment: Not with this example, but you can try other $2\times 2$ matrices.

Comment: Note that we can get a conjugating matrix with determinant $\pm 1$ if we replace $\mathbf Z$ with $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{2}]$, where the equation $2a^2 - 5c^2 = -1$ has the solution $a = \sqrt{2}$ and $c = 1$.  See the second answer at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/95536/stable-conjugacy-for-integer-matrices, which by fortunate coincidence uses exactly the same two matrices $A$ and $B$ as here.

Answer (score 3):

The matrices of order 2 $s=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ and $d=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & -1\end{pmatrix}$ are conjugate in $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbf{Q})$ (these are two reflections) but not over $\mathbf{Z}$ (since their reductions modulo 2 are not conjugate).

Moreover the conjugating matrix can be chosen to have determinant one: if $s=udu^{-1}$, choose $v=\begin{pmatrix}\det(u) & 0\\0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ and then $s=(uv^{-1})d(uv^{-1})^{-1}$.